# OpenCV: How to remove text from background

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Right now I am trying to create one program, which remove text from background but I am facing a lot of problem going through it

My approach is to use pytesseract to get text boxes and once I get boxes, I use cv2.inpaint to paint it and remove text from there. In short:

```
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT) # Get text
n_boxes = len(d['level']) # get boxes
for i in range(n_boxes): #  Looping through boxes
    # Get coordinates
    (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
    crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w] # Crop image
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = inverte(gray) # Inverse it
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    dst = cv2.inpaint(crop_img, thresh, 10, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA) # Then Inpaint
    img[y:y+h, x:x+w] = dst # Place back cropped image back to the source image
```

Now the problem is that I am not able to remove text completely
Image:
[image]

Now I am not sure what other method I can use to remove text from image, I am new to this that's why I am facing problem. Any help is much appreciated

Note: Image looks stretched because I resized it to show it in screen size

Original Image:

[image]

Comment: If the surrounding background is always this simple single-colored, just cut the Text with a margin & fill with the surrounding color. If it’s more complex, research into image reconstruction algorithms is necessary.

Comment: The background will be complex so thanks for the help, I'll look into reconstruction algorithms, my main motive is it replace text with custom one that's why I am planning to blur it first and then use text to replace it

Comment: Could you add your original input image?

Comment: @nathancy I have added the original image

Comment: @Shashank, do you want to remove all text including the two horizontal lines? What do you want to replace the text with?

Comment: @nathancy I just want to remove text, any text present over there, lines are just visuals so we can ignore that, also even if that gets removed then that's not a problem

Comment: Since the text color seems to be different from the background, you could try using Numpy thresholding with `np.where()` to get two different masks, one for black and one for the dark red then `cv2.bitwise_or()` to get a resulting mask of the text to be removed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an approach using morphological operations + contour filtering

- Convert image to grayscale
- Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image
- Perform morph close to connect words into a single contour
- Dilate to ensure that all bits of text are contained in the contour
- Find contours and filter using contour area
- Remove text by "filling" in the contour rectangle with the background color

---

I used chrome developer tools to determine the background color of the image which was `(222,228,251)`. If you want to dynamically determine the background color, you could try [finding the dominant color using k-means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793985/find-dominant-color-on-an-image/58244863#58244863). Here's the result

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

close_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15,3))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, close_kernel, iterations=1)

dilate_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,3))
dilate = cv2.dilate(close, dilate_kernel, iterations=1)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 800 and area < 15000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (222,228,251), -1)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it does solve my query, I need to figure out how I can dynamically get color of background and replace it. Also one quick question, sometime I have text which in grayscale might show up as white or black but at the end it is text right and it needs to be removed, so how can I select those text ?

Comment: But let's say I have image which has black text and in blue background some white text, so how do I figure out which threshold I need to make ? Because it will take black text into consideration but ignore the white one

Comment: [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) automatically calculates the threshold value so you shouldnt need to worry about finding the correct value